# Drop-Down List inside Update Panel not Triggering SelectedIndexChanged Event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, updatepanel

I'm in Asp.net 3.5 (Visual Studio 2008, VB). In a DetailsView, I've got several controls that need to perform hide/display actions, and I'm using an Update Panel.  The first control is a radio button ("rblAttemptType") with two options: *Phone Call* or *Letter*. If the user chooses *Phone Call*, a textbox to record the time of the call opens (there's also a textbox to record the date, but it applies to both calls and letters, so it stays visible). Choosing *Phone Call* also enables/disenables another radio button ("rblSuccess") that records whether the contact attempt was successful. The options for rblSuccess are *N/A*, *No* and *Yes*. The *N/A* option applies when the user chooses *Letter* from rblAttemptType, in which case rblSuccess  is also disabled (and more fields in the DetailsView become visible).

But if the user chooses *Phone Call* from rblAttemptType, rblSuccess is selection-cleared and enabled. Choosing *no* on rblSuccess reveals a drop-down list containing explanatory options (*no answer*, *left voicemail* etc.). One of the options is *Other*, which is supposed to reveal a textbox to record details.

Everything works, right up until that last step. It goes like this: I choose *Phone Call*, and the Time textbox appears. I type in the date and the time, then select *No* on rblSuccess, and the drop-down list appears. But when I make a selection on the drop-down list, nothing happens; i.e. the SelectedIndexChanged event assigned to the control isn't firing. And yes, it's set to AutoPostBack="True."

So--again--the SelectedIndexChanged subs for both of the radio buttons are working fine, but the one for the drop-down list isn't being hit.

Here's the code. I'm only including the parts of the DetailsView pertinent to this issue; let me know if you want the whole thing).

From the aspx page:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvAppointment" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="aID"
            Visible="False" Caption="Appointment Details" BorderColor="#189AA1" BorderStyle="Solid"
            BorderWidth="1px">
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" BorderStyle="None" Font-Names="Verdana,Arial,Helvetica"
                Font-Size="11px" Font-Strikeout="False" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#449c77" CssClass="white" Font-Bold="True" Width="15%"
                BorderColor="#189AA1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="aID" HeaderText="aID" Visible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attempt Type" SortExpression="AttemptType" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAttemptType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AttemptTypeDetails") %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAttemptMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# ContactAttemptMessage()%>'
                            HtmlEncode="False" CssClass="FireBrick9" HtmlEncodeFormatString="False" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAttemptMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# ContactAttemptMessage()%>'
                            HtmlEncode="False" CssClass="FireBrick9" HtmlEncodeFormatString="False" />
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblAttemptType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblAttemptTypeChanged" CssClass="Text9B">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Phone call</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Letter</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attempt Date" SortExpression="AttemptDate">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAttemptDateWithTime" runat="server" Text='<%# AttemptDateDetails() %>'></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txAttemptDate" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="False"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderAttemptDate" runat="server" TodaysDateFormat="mm/dd/yyyy"
                            TargetControlID="txAttemptDate">
                        </asp:CalendarExtender> &nbsp;
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelforAttempt" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="AttemptTimeLabel" runat="server" Text="Time of phone attempt (hh:mm AM/PM): "
                                    Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txAttemptTime" runat="server" ToolTip="Time should be in format XX:XX AM/PM"
                                    Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="txAttemptTimeTime_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server"
                                 CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" CultureDateFormat=""
                                    CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" CultureThousandsPlaceholder=""
                                    CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txAttemptTime" Mask="99:99 LL"
                                 ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False" MaskType="Number">
                                </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
                                <asp:Label ID="LabelSuccess" runat="server" Text="<br /><br />Was the attempt successful?"
                                 CssClass="Text8B" ></asp:Label>
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSuccess" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblSuccessChanged"
                                    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                     Enabled='<%# IIF(Eval("AttemptType")=1,"true","false") %>'>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">No</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">N/A</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblNoContactReason" runat="server" Text="<br />Please clarify the contact attempt result:"
                                            Visible="False" CssClass="smTextItalic"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlrncType" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsrncTypes" DataValueField="rncTypeID"
                                            DataTextField="rncType" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlrncTypeChanged">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSpecify" runat="server" Text="<br /><br />Please Explain:<br />"
                                            CssClass="smTextbold" Visible="False"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txrncOther" runat="server" Visible="false" ToolTip="Specific result (350 characters allowed)"
                                            TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="MultiLineInsert" Width="35%" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#449C77" BorderColor="#189AA1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
            <InsertRowStyle Width="80%" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana,Ariel,Helvetica"
                Font-Size="11px" />
            <EditRowStyle Width="77%" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Verdana,Ariel,Helvetica"
                Font-Size="11px" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CFCFCF" Font-Names="Verdana,Ariel,Helvetica" Font-Size="11px" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

From the VB code:

```
    Protected Sub rblAttemptTypeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim iAttemptTimeLabel As Label = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("AttemptTimeLabel"), Label)
    Dim itxAttemptTime As TextBox = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("txAttemptTime"), TextBox)
    Dim irblSuccess As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("rblSuccess"), RadioButtonList)
    Dim iUpdatePanelforAttempt As UpdatePanel = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("UpdatePanelforAttempt"), UpdatePanel)
    Dim AttemptType As Integer = 0
    If Not sender.selectedValue = String.Empty Then
        AttemptType = CInt(sender.selectedValue)
        ViewState("AttemptType") = CInt(sender.selectedValue)
        If AttemptType = 1 Then     'Phone
            If Not iAttemptTimeLabel Is Nothing Then
                iAttemptTimeLabel.Visible = True
            End If
            If Not itxAttemptTime Is Nothing Then
                itxAttemptTime.Visible = True
            End If
            If Not irblSuccess Is Nothing Then
                irblSuccess.Enabled = True
                irblSuccess.ClearSelection()
            End If
        ElseIf AttemptType = 2 Then     'Letter
            If Not iAttemptTimeLabel Is Nothing Then
                iAttemptTimeLabel.Visible = False
            End If
            If Not itxAttemptTime Is Nothing Then
                itxAttemptTime.Visible = False
            End If
            If Not irblSuccess Is Nothing Then
                irblSuccess.Enabled = False
        irblSuccess.SelectedIndex = 2
            End If
        End If
        If Not iUpdatePanelforAttempt Is Nothing Then
            iUpdatePanelforAttempt.Update()
        End If
    End If     
End Sub
Protected Sub rblSuccessChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim iddlrncType As DropDownList = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("ddlrncType"), DropDownList)
    Dim itxrncOther As TextBox = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("txrncOther"), TextBox)
    Dim ilblNoContactReason As Label = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("lblNoContactReason"), Label)
    Dim iUpdatePanelforAttempt As UpdatePanel = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("UpdatePanelforAttempt"), UpdatePanel)
Dim Success as Integer = -1
    If Not sender.selectedValue = String.Empty Then
        Success = CInt(sender.selectedValue)
        If Success = 1 Then
            If Not iddlrncType Is Nothing Then
                iddlrncType.Visible = True
            End If
            If Not ilblNoContactReason Is Nothing Then
                ilblNoContactReason.Visible = True
            End If
        Else    
            If Not iddlrncType Is Nothing Then
                iddlrncType.Visible = False
            End If
            If Not ilblNoContactReason Is Nothing Then
                ilblNoContactReason.Visible = False
            End If
        End If 
        If Not iUpdatePanelforAttempt Is Nothing Then
            iUpdatePanelforAttempt.Update()
        End If
    End If   
End Sub
Protected Sub ddlrncTypeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim ilblSpecify As Label = CType(dvAppointment.FindControl("lblSpecify"), Label)
    Dim itxrncOther As TextBox = CType(dvAppointment.FindControl("txrncOther"), TextBox)
    Dim iUpdatePanelforAttempt As UpdatePanel = DirectCast(dvAppointment.FindControl("UpdatePanelforAttempt"), UpdatePanel)
Dim rncTypeID as Integer = 0
    If Not sender.selectedValue = String.Empty AndAlso IsNumeric(sender.selectedvalue) Then
        rncTypeID = CInt(sender.selectedValue)
        If rncTypeID = 5 Then
            If Not itxrncOther Is Nothing Then
                itxrncOther.Visible = True
                itxrncOther.Focus()
                If Not ilblSpecify Is Nothing Then
                    ilblSpecify.Visible = True
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If Not itxrncOther Is Nothing Then
                itxrncOther.Visible = False
                If Not ilblSpecify Is Nothing Then
                    ilblSpecify.Visible = False
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If Not iUpdatePanelforAttempt Is Nothing Then
            iUpdatePanelforAttempt.Update()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried adding a second Update Panel, just around the drop-down list and the "Other" textbox, with the drop-down assigned as the AsyncPostBackTrigger, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: did not think you can stuff right inside of the details view a update panel. if you had/have 10 rows of data, you would wind up with 10 update panels nested inside of that list view. Put the update panel around the whole details view.

Comment: Yes, you can put update panels inside a DetailsView; I've done it many times, but never hit this particular complication. In any case, I removed the interior one and put it outside the DetailsView and the problem was cured! Thanks so much for the suggestion!